# Creating mulitple contact forms in drupal 7

Tags: 7, emails

I have installed the contact and contact_forms modules.
I have created different categories in the contact settings page.

I want multiple contact forms as I have multiple domains. For each domain I should have a separate contact form.

But that categories displayed in the drop down of the contact form.

Is it possible with the contact module to create multiple contact us forms like contact/site1, contact/site2, contact/site3 etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you consider using [Webform Module](http://drupal.org/project/webform). I generally prefer this over contact forms on my websites.

Answer (score 0):

Webforms is great but if you just need separate pages for the categories you can use https://www.drupal.org/project/contact_forms .

Comment: Is there any way to have multiple entity forms for multiple domains? So, basically I need a form to be re-used across all domains, but at the same time the form elements also should be different. Can this be achieved without adding a new form and then tagging it to the respective domains?